# wget and cvlc radio stream recording is stopping early

Tags: cron, streaming, wget, vlc, audio-recording

I currently have two different scripts scheduled using cron jobs to run daily to record a radio show I like. One uses wget that worked well for months and the other is using cvlc. I set up the cvlc when the wget started stopping the recording before the show was over. This worked as a backup for about two days before the cvlc started stopping early too, but at a different point of the show than the wget. The scripts are running on two separate Raspberry Pi machines. I had not made any changes to the Raspberry Pi or script before the problems started. Trying to determine what may be causing the issue.

**wget**

```
timeout 16500 wget -O /var/www/example.com/Show\ Name\ \($(date '+%B')\ $(date '+%-d'),\ $(date '+%Y')\).aac http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/Show.aac & sleep 16510 && ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/example.com/Show\ Name\ \($(date '+%B')\ $(date '+%-d'),\ $(date '+%Y')\).aac -c copy -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc /var/www/example.com/Show\ Name\ \($(date '+%B')\ $(date '+%-d'),\ $(date '+%Y')\).m4a
```

**cvlc**

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date '+%B')\ $(date '+%-d')\ $(date '+%Y')\
 

cvlc --run-time=16500 http://playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/Show --sout "#duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=raw,dst=/home/pi/Show Name ($NOW).mp3}" vlc://quit ;
```